# C++ uniform_int_distribution always returning min() on first invocation

Tags: c++, gcc, random

In at least one implementation of the standard library, the first invocation of a `std::uniform_int_distribution<>` does *not* return a random value, but rather the distribution's min value. That is, given the code:

```
default_random_engine engine( any_seed() );
uniform_int_distribution< int > distribution( smaller, larger );
auto x = distribution( engine );
assert( x == smaller );
```

...`x` will in fact be `smaller` for any values of `any_seed()`, `smaller`, or `larger`.

To play along at home, you can try a [code sample](http://ideone.com/23DL2k) that demonstrates this problem in gcc 4.8.1.

I trust this is *not* correct behavior? If it is correct behavior, why would a random distribution return this clearly non-random value?

Comment: Really? http://ideone.com/Xm9tRu

Comment: Yep, really. Did you try the linked code sample? Using time() does reveal something though, which is that for very large seeds the problem goes away. But there are many good cases in which a small, fixed seed is needed, and the problem is clearly there in those cases.

Comment: Its also a `gcc` only problem, in VS13, a seed as small as 2 produces numbers other than `smaller`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm seeing it in VS2012 too. :(

Answer (score 8):

## Explanation for the observed behavior

This is how `uniform_int_distribution` maps the random bits to numbers if the range of possible outcomes is smaller than the range of number the rng produces:

```
const __uctype __uerange = __urange + 1; // __urange can be zero
const __uctype __scaling = __urngrange / __uerange;
const __uctype __past = __uerange * __scaling;
do
  __ret = __uctype(__urng()) - __urngmin;
while (__ret >= __past);
__ret /= __scaling;
```

where `__urange` is `larger - smaller` and `__urngrange` is the difference between the maximum and the minimum value the rng can return. (Code from bits/uniform_int_dist.h in libstdc++ 6.1)

In our case, the rng `default_random_engine` is a `minstd_rand0`, which yields `__scaling == 195225785` for the range [0,10] you tested with. Thus, if `rng() < 195225785`, the distribution will return 0.

The first number a `minstd_rand0` returns is

```
(16807 * seed) % 2147483647
```

(where `seed == 0` gets adjusted to `1` btw). We can thus see that the first value produced by a `minstd_rand0` seeded with a number smaller than 11615 will yield 0 with the `uniform_int_distribution< int > distribution( 0, 10 );` you used. (mod off-by-one-errors on my part. ;) )

You mentioned the problem going away for bigger seeds: As soon as the seeds get big enough to actually make the mod operation do something, we cannot simply assign a whole range of values to the same output by division, so the results will look better.

## Does that mean (libstdc++'s impl of) <random> is broken?

No. You introduced significant bias in what is supposed to be a random 32 bit seed by always choosing it small. That bias showing up in the results is not surprising or evil. For random seeds, even your `minstd_rand0` will yield a fairly uniformly random first value. (Though the sequence of numbers after that will not be of great statistical quality.)

## What can we do about this?

**Case 1:** You want random number of high statistical quality.

For that, you use a better rng like `mt19937` and seed its *entire* state space. For the Mersenne Twister, that's 624 32-bit integers. (For reference, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device) is my attempt to do this properly with some helpful suggestions in the answer.)

**Case 2:** You really want to use those small seeds only.

We can still get decent results out of this. The problem is that pseudo random number generators commonly depend "somewhat continuously" on their seed. To ship around this, we discard enough numbers to let the initially similar sequences of output diverge. So if your seed must be small, you can initialize your rng like this:

```
std::mt19937 rng(smallSeed);
rng.discard(700000);
```

It is vital that you use a good rng like the Mersenne Twister for this. I do not know of any method to get even decent values out of a poorly seeded `minstd_rand0`, for example see [this train-wreck](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xmP6aW8u8643gG21). Even if seeded properly, the statistical properties of a `mt19937` are superior by far.

Concerns about the large state space or slow generation you sometimes hear about are usually of no concern outside the embedded world. According to [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators) and [cacert.at](http://www.cacert.at/cgi-bin/rngresults), the MT is even way faster than `minstd_rand0`.

You still need to do the discard trick though, even if your results look good to the naked eye without. It takes less than a millisecond on my system, and you don't seed rngs very often, so there is no reason not to.

Note that I am not able to give you a sharp estimate for the number of discards we need, I took that value from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/109518/47293), it links [this paper](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Elecuyer/myftp/papers/lfsr04.pdf) for a rational. I don't have the time to work through that right now.

Comment: On a slight tangent… I stumbled over the `__scaling == 195225785` part. It's correct, but not obvious IMO (why is it not 195225786?). It's because the maximum value returned by `minstd_rand0` is 2^31-2 (x modulo 2^31-1), and the minimum is 1, so the number of distinct values that can be returned is also 2^31-2, which is precisely 1 less than the next multiple of 11, therefore the division truncates down to 195225785. (0 cannot be returned, which follows from the fact that seeding with 0 is translated to seeding with 1, and some group theory, but I won't go into *that* now…)