# using std::uniform_real_distribution in a function that is called in main

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to use the  std::uniform_real_distribution in a function that is called in main().

I seed the generator as follows in main():

```
 unsigned seed = 
 std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
 std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
 std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);
```

further on in main i call:

```
double number = distribution(generator)
```

when i need a random number.

The problem is that i also need ( many millions )
of random numbers in a function.

imagine a function that i call in main():

```
int main(){

  void function(){

    number = distribution(generator)
  }

  return 0;
}
```

how to do this? how to "access" the random number generator in a function.

many thanks!

Comment: You pass it to the function?

Comment: Don't use the time as seed, that's not random at all. Don't use `std::default_random_engine`, that's often bad ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21843172/3002139)). You can find a way to properly seed a good RNG in my question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/109260/47293).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function out of it. I recommend using `std::mt19937` as the random number generator and seeding it with (at least) `std::random_device`.

Something like this:

```
inline
double random_number(double min, double max)
{
    // use thread_local to make this function thread safe
    thread_local static std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};
    thread_local static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist;
    using pick = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>::param_type;

    return dist(mt, pick(min, max));
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << i << ": " << random_number(2.5, 3.9) << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
1: 3.73887
2: 3.68129
3: 3.41809
4: 2.64881
5: 2.93931
6: 3.15629
7: 2.76597
8: 3.55753
9: 2.90251
```

Comment: thanks! i made a similar thing after reading your comment. (it works!)