# Fixing Neural Net vanishing gradients problem?

Tags: c++, neural-network

This is going to be a long one. I am still very new to coding, started 3 months ago so I know my code is not perfect, any criticism beyond the question is more than welcome. I have specifically avoided using pointers because I do not fully understand them, I can use them but I dont trust that I will use them correctly in a program like this.

First things first, I have a version of this where there is only 1 hidden layer and the net works perfectly. I have started running into problems since I tried to expand the number of hidden layers.
Some info on the net:
-I am using softmax output activation as I have 3 output neurons.
-I am using tanh as my activation function on the rest of the net.
-The file being read for the input has a format of
"input: 0.56 0.76 0.23 0.67"
"output: 0.0 0.0 1.0" (this is the target)
-The weights for connecting layer 1 neuron to layer 2 neuron are stored in layer 1 one neuron.
-The bias's for each neuron are stored in that neuron.
-The target is 1.0 0.0 0.0 if the sum of the input numbers is below one, 0.0 1.0 0.0 if sum is between 1 and 2, 0.0 0.0 1.0 if sum is above 2.
-using L1 regularization.

Those problems specifically being:

- The softmax output values do not move from an relatively equalised range ie:
  (position 1 and 2 in the target vector have a roughly 50/50 occurance rate while position 3 less than 3% occurance rate. so by relatively equalised I mean the softmax output generally looks something like
  "0.56.... 0.48.... 0.02..." even after 500 epochs.
- The weights at the hidden layer closer to inputlayer dont change much at all, which is what i think vanishing gradients are. I might be wrong on this. But the weights at hiddenlayer closest to output are ending up at between -50 & 50 (which i think is okay?)

Things I have tried:

- I have tried using Relu, parametric Relu, exponential Relu, but with all of these the softmax output value for neuron 3 keeps rising, the other 2 neurons values keep falling. these values continue their trajectory until either 500 epochs have been reached or they just turn into nans. (I think this is to do with the structure of my code rather than the Relu function itself).

If I set the number of hidden layers above 3 while using relu, it immediately spits out nans, within the first epoch.
The backprop function is pretty long, but this is specifically because I have deconstructed it many times over to try and figure out where I might be mismatching values or something. I do have it in a condensed version but I feel I have a higher chance of being completely off the mark there than I do if I have it deconstructed.
I have included the Relu function code that I used, it is the first time I use it so I might be wrong on that aswell but I dont think so, I have double checked multiple times. The Relu in the code is specifically "Elu" or exponential relu.

here is the code for the net:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

double randomt(double x, double y)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(x, y);
    return dist(mt);
}
class InputN
{
public:
    double val{};
    std::vector <double> weights{};
};
class HiddenN
{
public:
    double preactval{};
    double actval{};
    double actvalPD{};
    double preactvalpd{};
    std::vector <double> weights{};
    double bias{};
};
class OutputN
{
public:
    double preactval{};
    double actval{};
    double preactvalpd{};
    double bias{};
};
class Net
{
public:
    std::vector <InputN> inneurons{};
    std::vector <std::vector <HiddenN>> hiddenneurons{};
    std::vector <OutputN> outputneurons{};
    double lambda{ 0.015 };
    double alpha{ 0.02 };
};
double tanhderiv(double val)
{
    return 1 - tanh(val) * tanh(val);
}
double Relu(double val)
{
    if (val < 0) return 0.01 *(exp(val) - 1);
    else return val;
}
double Reluderiv(double val)
{
    if (val < 0) return Relu(val) + 0.01;
    else  return 1;
}
double regularizer(double weight)
{
    double absval{};
    if (weight < 0) absval = weight - weight - weight;
    else if (weight > 0 || weight == 0) absval = weight;
    else;
    if (absval > 0) return 1;
    else if (absval < 0) return -1;
    else if (absval == 0) return 0;
    else return 2;

}
void feedforward(Net& net)
{
    double sum{};
    int prevlayer{};
    for (size_t Hsize = 0; Hsize < net.hiddenneurons.size(); Hsize++)
    {
        //std::cout << "in first loop" << '\n';
        prevlayer = Hsize - 1;
        for (size_t Hel = 0; Hel < net.hiddenneurons[Hsize].size(); Hel++)
        {
            //std::cout << "in second loop" << '\n';
            if (Hsize == 0)
            {
                //std::cout << "in first if" << '\n';
                for (size_t Isize = 0; Isize < net.inneurons.size(); Isize++)
                {
                    //std::cout << "in fourth loop" << '\n';
                    sum += (net.inneurons[Isize].val * net.inneurons[Isize].weights[Hel]);
                }
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].preactval = net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].bias + sum;
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].actval = tanh(sum);
                sum = 0;
                //std::cout << "first if done" << '\n';
            }
            else
            {
                //std::cout << "in else" << '\n';
                for (size_t prs = 0; prs < net.hiddenneurons[prevlayer].size(); prs++)
                {
                    //std::cout << "in fourth loop" << '\n';
                    sum += net.hiddenneurons[prevlayer][prs].actval * net.hiddenneurons[prevlayer][prs].weights[Hel];
                }
                //std::cout << "fourth loop done" << '\n';
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].preactval = net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].bias + sum;
                net.hiddenneurons[Hsize][Hel].actval = tanh(sum);
                //std::cout << "else done" << '\n';
                sum = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "first loop done " << '\n';
    int lasthid = net.hiddenneurons.size() - 1;
    for (size_t Osize = 0; Osize < net.outputneurons.size(); Osize++)
    {
        for (size_t Hsize = 0; Hsize < net.hiddenneurons[lasthid].size(); Hsize++)
        {
            sum += (net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][Hsize].actval * net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][Hsize].weights[Osize]);
        }
        net.outputneurons[Osize].preactval = net.outputneurons[Osize].bias + sum;
    } 
}
void softmax(Net& net)
{
    double sum{};
    for (size_t Osize = 0; Osize < net.outputneurons.size(); Osize++)
    {
        sum += exp(net.outputneurons[Osize].preactval);
    }
    for (size_t Osize = 0; Osize < net.outputneurons.size(); Osize++)
    {
        net.outputneurons[Osize].actval = exp(net.outputneurons[Osize].preactval) / sum;
    }
}
void lossfunc(Net& net, std::vector <double> target)
{
    int pos{ -1 };
    double val{};
    for (size_t t = 0; t < target.size(); t++)
    {
        pos += 1;
        if (target[t] > 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (size_t s = 0; net.outputneurons.size(); s++)
    {
        val = -log(net.outputneurons[pos].actval);
    }
}
void backprop(Net& net, std::vector<double>& target)
{
    for (size_t outI = 0; outI < net.outputneurons.size(); outI++)
    {
        double PD = target[outI] - net.outputneurons[outI].actval;
        net.outputneurons[outI].preactvalpd = PD * -1;      
    }
    size_t lasthid = net.hiddenneurons.size() - 1; 
    for (size_t LH = 0; LH < net.hiddenneurons[lasthid].size(); LH++)
    {
        for (size_t LHW = 0; LHW < net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][LH].weights.size(); LHW++)
        {
            double weight = net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][LH].weights[LHW];
            double PD = net.outputneurons[LHW].preactvalpd * net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][LH].actval;
            PD = PD * -1;
            double delta = PD - (net.lambda * regularizer(weight));
            weight = weight + (net.alpha * delta);
            net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][LH].weights[LHW] = weight;
        }
        
    }
    for (size_t OB = 0; OB < net.outputneurons.size(); OB++)
    {
        double bias = net.outputneurons[OB].bias;
        double BPD = net.outputneurons[OB].preactvalpd;
        BPD = BPD * -1;
        double Delta = BPD;
        bias = bias + (net.alpha * Delta);
    }
    for (size_t HPD = 0; HPD < net.hiddenneurons[lasthid].size(); HPD++)
    {

        double PD{};
        for (size_t HW = 0; HW < net.outputneurons.size(); HW++)
        {
            PD += net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][HPD].weights[HW] * net.outputneurons[HW].preactvalpd;
        }
        net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][HPD].actvalPD = PD;
        PD = 0;
    }
    for (size_t HPD = 0; HPD < net.hiddenneurons[lasthid].size(); HPD++)
    {
        net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][HPD].preactvalpd = net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][HPD].actvalPD * tanhderiv(net.hiddenneurons[lasthid][HPD].preactval);
    }
    for (size_t AllHid = net.hiddenneurons.size() - 2; AllHid > -1; AllHid--)
    {
        size_t uplayer = AllHid + 1;
        for (size_t cl = 0; cl < net.hiddenneurons[AllHid].size(); cl++)
        {
            for (size_t clw = 0; clw < net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][cl].weights.size(); clw++)
            {
                double weight = net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][cl].weights[clw];
                double PD = net.hiddenneurons[uplayer][clw].preactvalpd * net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][cl].actval;
                PD = PD * -1;
                double delta = PD - (net.lambda * regularizer(weight));
                weight = weight + (net.alpha * delta);
                net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][cl].weights[clw] = weight;
            }
        }
        for (size_t up = 0; up < net.hiddenneurons[uplayer].size(); up++)
        {
            double bias = net.hiddenneurons[uplayer][up].bias;
            double PD = net.hiddenneurons[uplayer][up].preactvalpd;
            PD = PD * -1;
            double delta = PD;
            bias = bias + (net.alpha * delta);
        }
        for (size_t APD = 0; APD < net.hiddenneurons[AllHid].size(); APD++)
        {

            double PD{};
            for (size_t APDW = 0; APDW < net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][APD].weights.size(); APDW++)
            {
                PD += net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][APD].weights[APDW] * net.hiddenneurons[uplayer][APDW].preactvalpd;
            }
            net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][APD].actvalPD = PD;
            PD = 0;
        }
        for (size_t PPD = 0; PPD < net.hiddenneurons[AllHid].size(); PPD++)
        {
            double PD = net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][PPD].actvalPD * tanhderiv(net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][PPD].preactval);
            net.hiddenneurons[AllHid][PPD].preactvalpd = PD;
        }
    }
    for (size_t IN = 0; IN < net.inneurons.size(); IN++)
    {
        for (size_t INW = 0; INW < net.inneurons[IN].weights.size(); INW++)
        {
            double weight = net.inneurons[IN].weights[INW];
            double PD = net.hiddenneurons[0][INW].preactvalpd * net.inneurons[IN].val;
            PD = PD * -1;
            double delta = PD - (net.lambda * regularizer(weight));
            weight = weight + (net.alpha * delta);
            net.inneurons[IN].weights[INW] = weight;
        }
    }
    for (size_t hidB = 0; hidB < net.hiddenneurons[0].size(); hidB++)
    {
        double bias = net.hiddenneurons[0][hidB].bias;
        double PD = net.hiddenneurons[0][hidB].preactvalpd;
        PD = PD * -1;
        double delta = PD;
        bias = bias + (net.alpha * delta);
        net.hiddenneurons[0][hidB].bias = bias;
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::vector <double> invals{ };
    std::vector <double> target{ };
    Net net;
    InputN Ineuron;
    HiddenN Hneuron;
    OutputN Oneuron;
    int IN = 4;
    int HIDLAYERS = 4;
    int HID = 8;
    int OUT = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < IN; i++)
    {
        net.inneurons.push_back(Ineuron);
        for (int m = 0; m < HID; m++)
        {
            net.inneurons.back().weights.push_back(randomt(0.0, 0.5));
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "first loop done" << '\n';
    for (int s = 0; s < HIDLAYERS; s++)
    {
        net.hiddenneurons.push_back(std::vector <HiddenN>());
        if (s == HIDLAYERS - 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < HID; i++)
            {
                net.hiddenneurons[s].push_back(Hneuron);
                for (int m = 0; m < OUT; m++)
                {
                    net.hiddenneurons[s].back().weights.push_back(randomt(0.0, 0.5));
                }
                net.hiddenneurons[s].back().bias = 1.0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < HID; i++)
            {
                net.hiddenneurons[s].push_back(Hneuron);
                for (int m = 0; m < HID; m++)
                {
                    net.hiddenneurons[s].back().weights.push_back(randomt(0.0, 0.5));
                }
                net.hiddenneurons[s].back().bias = 1.0;
            }
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "second loop done" << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < OUT; i++)
    {
        net.outputneurons.push_back(Oneuron);
        net.outputneurons.back().bias = randomt(0.0, 0.5);
    }
    //std::cout << "third loop done" << '\n';
    int count{};
    std::ifstream fileread("N.txt");
    for (int epoch = 0; epoch < 500; epoch++)
    {
        count = 0;
        if (epoch == 100 || epoch == 100 * 2 || epoch == 100 * 3 || epoch == 100 * 4 || epoch == 499)
        {
            printvals("no", net);
        }
        fileread.clear(); fileread.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        while (fileread.is_open())
        {

            std::cout << '\n' << "epoch: " << epoch << '\n';
            std::string fileline{};
            fileread >> fileline;
            if (fileline == "in:")
            {
                std::string input{};
                double nums{};
                std::getline(fileread, input);
                std::stringstream ss(input);
                while (ss >> nums)
                {
                    invals.push_back(nums);
                }
            }
            if (fileline == "out:")
            {
                std::string output{};
                double num{};
                std::getline(fileread, output);
                std::stringstream ss(output);
                while (ss >> num)
                {
                    target.push_back(num);
                }
            }
            count += 1;
            if (count == 2)
            {
                for (size_t inv = 0; inv < invals.size(); inv++)
                {
                    net.inneurons[inv].val = invals[inv];
                }
                //std::cout << "calling feedforward" << '\n';
                feedforward(net);
                //std::cout << "ff done" << '\n';
                softmax(net);
                printvals("output", net);
                std::cout << "target: " << '\n';
                for (auto element : target) std::cout << element << " / ";
                std::cout << '\n';
                backprop(net, target);
                invals.clear();
                target.clear();
                count = 0;
            }
            if (fileread.eof()) break;
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "fourth loop done" << '\n';

    return 1;
}
```

Much aprecciated to anyone who actually made it through all that! :)

Comment: Your random number function is not particularly efficient because it recreates a new generator every time it is called and then seeds it from a slow generator source. I recommend making the generator `static` or `thread_local`,  something more like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528415/using-stduniform-real-distribution-in-a-function-that-is-called-in-main/44528606#44528606

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will definitely use that from now on :)

Comment: So thanks to your comment, I came across an initialisation method called xavier initialisation and now my net works even better than before, but only if i have one hidden layer.. so im still not sure whats going on haha. but thanks so much for the suggestion!